# .htaccess gives error 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've inherited some website and I'm trying to migrate it to another provider but apparently there's some problem with my .htaccess file as it goes to the loop and gives error 500.

This is my file, apparently there's something wrong with rewrite rules but I've no idea what

```
AddHandler php5.3-fastcgi php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^css(/)?$ /sheets/ [R] 

RewriteRule ^lang/?([0-9]+)? /index.php?sl=$1
RewriteRule ^photo* /index.php
RewriteRule ^bio* /biography.php
RewriteRule ^albums* /albums.php
RewriteRule ^contact* /contact.php

php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_source off
php_flag report_memleaks on
php_flag track_errors on
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
php_value error_log /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
php_value error_reporting -1
php_value log_errors_max_len 0
```

Comment: what is the exact error given by the server? Also, you should have a look at the log of the server.

Comment: You should also try commenting them out and see which one fails, if you don't have access to the servers configuration.

Comment: And if commenting lines doesnt work try commenting entire blocks, or remove all and add block per block or line by line

Comment: problem seems to be in those lines RewriteRule ^photo* /index.php
RewriteRule ^bio* /biography.php
RewriteRule ^albums* /albums.php
RewriteRule ^contact* /contact.php